# Windows 8 (64bit) can't update: 0x800F0922

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, .net-3.5

I finally decided to make a thread after fighting with this problem for very long.

First, let's see what i have in the registry:
[image: Registry editor]

Second, I have these pending updates:
[image: Updates]

What i try to do now, is: update my computer :o

The problem is that when i restart my computer to finish the installation, i will reach the point saying 98% completed (or something similar), then it completes i think, but it says: reverting updates.

When i boot up again, i went to the event log, to find these errors:
[image: Windows error log viewer]

.net Framework 3.5 is enabled in windows features.
I suspect it might have something to do with my boot, i have a different boot record than windows'

Comment: Can you install all the other updates besides KB2795944?  Have you tried installing it [manually](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36634)?

Comment: they all return the same error

Comment: zip and upload the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS (copy the folder first to the desktop) and post a link here.

Comment: So what i did: deleted the content of CBS, tried to update again, got the error again and uploaded the logs (so that you would have a fresh log without too much irrelevant stuff): http://www.ayg.dk/CBS.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the EFI Boot components fails for your:

```
2013-02-17 22:53:09, Info                  CSI    000000aa Begin executing advanced installer phase 38 (0x00000026) index 78 (0x000000000000004e) (sequence 117)
    Old component: [ml:358{179},l:356{178}]"Microsoft-Windows-BootEnvironment-Core-BootManager-EFI, Culture=neutral, Version=6.2.9200.16420, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS"
    New component: [ml:358{179},l:356{178}]"Microsoft-Windows-BootEnvironment-Core-BootManager-EFI, Culture=neutral, Version=6.2.9200.16384, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS"
    Install mode: install
    Installer ID: {c5f0e9d7-e844-4507-89e4-701b5a747221}
    Installer name: [34]"CSI Boot File Servicing (BFSVC) AI"
2013-02-17 22:53:09, Error                 CSI    000000ab@2013/2/17:21:53:09.374 (F) base\wcp\plugins\bfsvc\bfsvc.cpp(218): Error HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(123) originated in function Windows::WCP::Bfsvc::BasicInstaller::Install expression: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError())
[gle=0x80004005]
```

Use boot recovery option to repair the BCD store. Also make sure the 350MB partition which contains the bootloader is not full.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to solve some of the problem i guess. But windows update is still not working properly, The only missing update is now this one: KB2770816
http://ayg.dk/CBS.log

Comment: To answer myself, according to this site: bit.ly/ZvFlWM the cause of that error is an entry in the registry db. I tried creating it myself but i couldn't, regedit said it already existed even though it didn't. I downloaded a software called: Registrar Registry Manager. Then created the entry, and it updated like a charm!
Again, thank you magicandre, you certainly are magic :p I looked in the log myself but didn't see that.

Comment: nice to hear that the issue is fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue.

After uninstallation of IObit Start menu 8 the Windows Update are working.

Answer (score 0):

I recently have the Windows 8.1 update failing continuously at 98%.

The errors in C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log were:
    [AU_SHUTDOWN_INSTALL_FAILED]    101 {F8C84DA5-5880-403A-B908-64E113527A12}  219 800f0922    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Content Install Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800f0922

The error in C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log was:
    Error                 CSI    0000015d@2017/5/3:13:07:13.557 (F) base\wcp\plugins\bfsvc\bfsvc.cpp(218): Error HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_DISK_FULL) originated in function Windows::WCP::Bfsvc::BasicInstaller::Install expression: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()) [gle=0x80004005]

I had two partitions of my disk and both of them had plenty of free space.

The error was due to the fact that the hidden recovery / MBR partition was full. I had to delete some files that were copied there by a tool I used to backup partitions.

Basically here are the steps I used:

- Input “cmd” into Windows search box and open the Command Prompt as an administrator.
- Then type “diskpart”.
- Type “list disk” command to list all your hard disks in the computer.
- Input “select disk n”, where is n is the number of the hard disk that the recovery partition on it.
- Type “list partition” to show all the partitions on the selected hard disk.
- Type “select partition m”, where m is the number of the recovery partition.
- Then type “assign”: the system will assign a drive letter automatically.

After these commands, you can see the recovery partition in Windows Explorer (try refresh if the partition is still not visible).  You can see how much free space is left and, if necessary, do some cleaning (just make sure you know what you delete). In my case, I had 70 K free from a total of 350 M. Once I did the cleaning, it showed 290 M free.

Then you have to hide the recovery partition: basically the same as the steps of unhide, the only different is the last step: type “remove letter=e”, the e is the drive letter of the recovery partition.

After this, I was able to install the updates with no error.